# RewriteCond to exclude particular directory

Tags: .htaccess

I used to have a separate /m directory for mobile (serving m.example.com), but have merged all those files into the main site.

I've set up redirects for all the moved files which are working fine. However, one directory, /games no longer exists in the root directory and I want to stop requests for that directory (e.g. m.example.com/games/game1.php) before they even get to the root.

In the empty m/ directory (only has a .htaccess and ErrorDocument) I have this first:

`RewriteRule ^games/ - [L,R=404]`

Without it, the request produces an infinite loop on the root domain. Seems to me this should stop the request altogether, but it doesn't.

Then, I have

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^games [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

I expect the request to finish at the first line, `RewriteRule ^games/ - [L,R=404]` but it currently is going:

http://m.example.com/games/game1.php -> https://m.example.com/my-custom-404-page-on-m.php -> https://www.example.com/my-custom-404-page-on-m.php

So it's correctly flagging the request as a 404, sending it to the custom 404, but not stopping there. The final redirect is still sending it to the main site and the main site doesn't have `my-custom-404-page-on-m.php`, so returns a 404.

I've tried many other combinations like

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/games [NC]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^games.* [NC]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^games\/ [NC]`

but they all give the same result.

How can I get the failed request to stop in the "m" domain and not go on to the main site?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it out.

My final `RewriteCond` should have addressed the file `my-custom-404-page-on-m.php`, not the `/games` directory.

Also, it does still need the `RewriteRule` for `games/` directory.

The full solution for `.htaccess` in "m" domain:

```
# Even though this directory does not exist, need to include this:
RewriteRule ^games/ - [L,R=404]

# Send ordinary pages on their way, except for the ErrorDocument
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-custom-404-page-on-m\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Catch any games/ directory 404 cases here
ErrorDocument 404 /my-custom-404-page-on-m.php
```